# Bold/Color a specific line in stack traces

Tags: intellij-idea

After years of programming, I still find it time-consuming sifting through stack traces.

Is there a way to bold or color the first line in every stack trace that starts with a particular package name?  For example, I could be using a framework, and while the exception is thrown in the framework, the real cause is often in my code.  So, I'd like to bold or color the first line where my code starts in the trace if it's found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the grep highlight plugin
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console